# How do I fixed my selection of extensions in sublime text?

Tags: typescript, sublimetext

I was development in typescript. I used sublime text to code. I had downloaded some plugin in my sublime text and it can hint or auto-complete for me. But when I open typescript, sublime text is default to use its built-in extension.

[image]

The first typescript is by I download. The second one is built-in in sublime text. I expect that I can avoid to be lead to the second one by sublime text and it's default to use the first one.

How do I set sumbline text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to change the config file on sublime, I've not tried setting the same issue but I've configured theme using the same to use as a default. You can refer to the link on sublime for [Settings](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/settings.html)